# RSA-OAEP Input Parameters

Tags: rsa, padding, oaep

When creating padding for RSA using OAEP, a message is prepared as follows:

```
Hash(Input Parameter) || Zeros || 1 || Message
```

My question is, what should the Input Parameter be? It must be known to both sides, I understand it can be an empty array (string, whatever). In that case there is no need to calculate the hash, hashing an empty input always produces the same result.

Is there a recommendation regarding what to use as the input parameter?

I'm thinking about hashing the public modulus n, which is already known by all parties. It's not necessary I suppose since the random seed from the other part of the OAEP procedure will change the final value anyway, but I'm still curious what is considered "best practice", or some requirement that I missed.

Comment: See [PKCS#1v2.1](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) which calls that a Label, and states it might be empty, or in some specified syntax. See [here](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-1.pdf), in particular Remark 3, for a discussion on possible uses.

Comment: @fgieu That might be considered an answer. Answered questions will receive less attention from other experts (and nutcases such as me :) ).

Comment: @owlstead: Feel free to expand this into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Input Parameter* in the question is called a *Label* in [PKCS#1v2.1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125); this [standard](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) states it might be empty, or be expressed in some specified syntax. I borrow Victor Shoup's explanation from Remark 3 in this [paper](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-1.pdf):

> A *label* is a byte string that is effectively bound to the ciphertext
>   in a nonmalleable way. It may contain data that is implicit from
>   context and need not be encrypted, but that should nevertheless be
>   bound to the ciphertext. We view a label to be a byte string that is
>   meaningful to the application using the encryption scheme, and that is
>   independent of the implementation of the encryption scheme. For
>   example, there are key exchange protocols in which one party, say *A*,
>   encrypts a session key *K* under the public key of the other party,
>   say *B*. In order for the protocol to be secure, party *A*'s identity
>   (or public key or certificate) must be non-malleably bound to the
>   ciphertext. One way to do this is simply to append this identity to
>   the cleartext. However, this creates an unnecessarily large
>   ciphertext, since *A*'s identity is typically already known to *B* in
>   the context of such a protocol. A good implementation of the labeling
>   mechanism achieves the same effect, without increasing the size of the
>   ciphertext. Labels may also be of arbitrary and variable length, but
>   we do not impose the restriction that the encryption and decryption
>   algorithms should be able to process labels as streams. Both the ECIES
>   and RSA-OAEP submissions include the notion of a label (where it is
>   called an *encoding parameter*), although absolutely no indication was
>   given as to the role or function of a label. Nevertheless, it seems to
>   be a potentially useful feature (..)